# kernel 3.13.0-37 crased on ubuntu 14.04. also questions about 2 graphic cards

Tags: 14.04, kernel, dell

My question is about the linux kernel. It may be related to some issues regarding the video cards, that's why I mention them.

I have Ubuntu 14.04, with linux kernel 3.13.0-37, on a Dell Vostro 3550 with 2 video cards (intel -integrated in the CPU- and AMD Radeon)

Today I had an issue with the suspended state: the mouse and keyboard were not functioning after that, so I had to press the button to turn it off and restart. After trying various things (the last one was to upgrade the nvidia driver, which was probably a mistake - my previous Dell Laptop had a nvidia video card, this one has AMD radeon), I ended up not being able to boot at all.

I booted with the previous kernel version 3.13.0-36 and all my issues were gone! For now, I simply deleted the 3.13.0-37 kernel, but I wonder if this is a good idea on the long term. Should I try to reinstall the 3.13.0-37 kernel?

Can I find out what went wrong in the first place? I was not even online when the suspended state problem first arised, so it cannot be a recent upgrade. About the nvidia driver instead of radeon - this is clearly my mistake. Should I delete the nvidia driver? And should I install a radeon driver? How do I find out which video card is in use and how can I manage the 2 graphic cards?

Maybe I need to ask another question about the video cards, for now I would just like to know what to do about the linux kernel.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. And yes, please post separate questions separately.

Answer (score 0):

If a new kernel breaks your system and your system works fine with the old kernel, simply continue using the old kernel until another kernel version is released in the repositories.

There is either a bug in the kernel or an unfortunate compatibility issue between the new kernel and one or more of your system drivers.

Edit after additional context:

Yes, you should try purging the package and re-installing it:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had already used the latest kernel 3.13.0-37 for a long while without any problems. It's just that yesterday I had that issue with the suspended state, then I assume I messed it up myself trying to fix it. So I just wanted to know if it's ok to use the previous kernel on a long term, or if I should try to upgrade (as it was before yesterday, actually)

Comment: should I remove the nvidia driver first?

Comment: If it's proprietary, then I would say yes. If it's nouveau, then it shouldn't matter.